# SSIS Package consistently fails with 'WriteToServer requires an open and available Connection' with Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, ado.net

SSIS newbie here, learning fast!

I have successfully extracted data from my Azure SQL Server 12 staging tables, transformed it and I'm attempting to load the transformed data back to the Azure SQL Server using an SSIS **ADO.NET Destination** component. This has been successful for most of the 'fact' tables I'm loading but for one I keep getting the following error:

> [factTable [137]] Error: An exception has occurred during data
> insertion, the message returned from the provider is: WriteToServer
> requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current
> state is closed.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
> ProcessInput method on component "factTable" (137) failed with error
> code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input"
> (144). The identified component returned an error from the
> ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
> error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.

Nothing is running on the Azure SQL Server that would affect the connection.

Could there be some buffer size setting as it always happens at the same point in the record write? Any thoughts? [SSIS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbaWQ.png)

Many thanks

Comment: Please try to switch connection from ADO.NET to the newest **Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, changing the data destinations to use the **OLE DB Destination** worked a treat although I had some reformatting to do due to string incompatibility (DT_WSTR vs DT_STR) but all sorted now. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Let's create an answer from it, so the others would know too about the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to switch connection from ADO.NET to the newest Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15